# Rails, how to get hours of a datetime in the correct time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, timezone

I have an offer model. and when I access it from the command line, it is displayed in the following format:

```
1.9.3p392 :058 > o = Offer.last
 => #<Offer id: 15, title: "Testing", valid_from: "2013-04-12 09:00:00", valid_until: "2013-04-12 14:00:00", created_at: "2013-04-12 18:31:54", updated_at: "2013-04-12 18:31:54">
```

In this output, `valid_from` and `valid_until` are formatted as I would expect. however, when I access them directly, I get something different:

```
1.9.3p392 :059 > o.valid_from
   => Fri, 12 Apr 2013 05:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

The issue comes with this function I have inside of `app/models/offer_model.rb` :

```
  def start_hour
    self.valid_from.strftime('%l').to_i unless self.valid_from.nil?
  end
```

When I run this command, with the model above, the output is `5`. I would expect it to return `9` in this case. How can I get `start_hour` to return the hour adjusted for the time zone in this case?

Answer (score 0):

What Time zone are you using in config/application.rb? Rails adjust printed date to the Time Zone set in this file.

Comment: `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`  <-- from my config file

Comment: So this is it - [timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html) Try changing your time_zone to UTC (or just commenting this line out, as the default one time is UTC).